# How to count occurrences of a column value per ID in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

If I have a table like this in BigQuery

```
id    success
-------------
01    true
01    true
02    false
02    true
```

I would like to end up with this:

```
id    true    false
--------------------
01    2       0  
02    1       1
```

I've got this but I wondered if there was a more elegant way to do it?

```
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    (
        SELECT 
            count(*)
        FROM `my_table` t2
        WHERE t2.success = true and t2.id = t1.id
    ) as trueCount,
    (
        SELECT 
            count(*)
        FROM `my_table` t3
        WHERE t3.success = false and t3.id = t1.id
    ) as falseCount
FROM `my_table` t1
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I think that's best what you can get. But... ID usually is primary key and must be unique. I hope it's just for demo

Comment: which database are you using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider conditional aggregation which should work on almost all databases:

```sql
SELECT 
    t.id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.success = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS trueCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.success = false THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS falseCount
FROM `my_table` t
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: where come t2 and t3 from, this query makes no sense, besides without nknowig the rdms...

Comment: @nbk...whoops! Fixed. Again, this should work on most RDBMS's that support `CASE`.

Comment: that is better, but still the question lacks vital detail and should be closed

Comment: @nbk Have updated the title and question text to mention that I'm using BigQuery. t2 and t3 are table aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use condition aggregate function instead of the subquery.

```
SELECT id,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN success = true THEN 1 END) trueCount,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN success = false THEN 1 END) falseCount
FROM T
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

consider below approach for BigQuery

```
select * from your_table
pivot (count(*) for success in (true, false))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]